# error for displayed even it has not been submitted yet

Tags: php, error-handling, required

i just load the page yet the error has been displayed

```html
<?php

$nameErr = $emailErr = $idErr = $passwordErr = "";
$name = $email = $id = $password = "";

if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST") {
   if (empty($_POST["name"])) {
     $nameErr = "Name is required";
   } else {
     $name = test_input($_POST["name"]);
     // check if name only contains letters and whitespace
     if (!preg_match("/^[a-zA-Z ]*$/",$name)) {
       $nameErr = "Only letters and white space allowed"; 
     }
   }
   
   if (empty($_POST["email"])) {
     $emailErr = "Email is required";
   } else {
     $email = test_input($_POST["email"]);
     // check if e-mail address is well-formed
     if (!filter_var($email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)) {
       $emailErr = "Invalid email format"; 
     }
   }
     
   if (empty($_POST["id"])) {
      $genderErr = "Matric number is required";
   } else {
     $website = test_input($_POST["id"]);
    
     if (!preg_match("/^[0-9].*$/",$id)){
       $idErr = "Only numbers allowed"; }
     }
   }

   if (empty($_POST["password"])) {
     $passwordErr = "Password is required";
   } else {
     $password = test_input($_POST["password"]);
     // check if name only contains letters and whitespace
     if (!preg_match("/^[a-zA-Z0-9]+$/",$password)) {
       $nameErr = "Special characters are not allowed"; 
     }
   }

function test_input($data) {
   $data = trim($data);
   $data = stripslashes($data);
   $data = htmlspecialchars($data);
   return $data;
}
?>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1" />
<title>Pendaftaran Kali Pertama</title>
<style type="text/css">
<!--
.style1 {
 color: #FFCC00;
 font-weight: bold;
  
}
.error{ color:#FFCC00}
-->
</style>

</head>

<body>
<div align="center">
    <form  method="post" action="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($_SERVER["PHP_SELF"]);?>">
      
      <table width="62%" border="0" cellpadding="2" cellspacing="2">
        <tr>
          <td height="35" colspan="4" bgcolor="#660066"><div align="center" class="style1">PENDAFTARAN KALI PERTAMA </div></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td width="33%"><div align="right"><strong>Nama </strong></div></td>
          <td width="5%"><div align="center"><strong>:</strong></div></td>
          <td width="62%"><input name="name" type="text" size="50"  /><span class="error">* <?php echo $nameErr;?></span></td>
          
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td><div align="right"><strong>No. Pelajar </strong></div></td>
          <td><div align="center"><strong>:</strong></div></td>
          <td><input name="id" type="text" size="50" maxlength="10"  /><span class="error">* <?php echo $idErr;?></span></td>
        
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td><div align="right"><strong>Kata Laluan(8 aksara sahaja)</strong></div></td>
          <td><div align="center"><strong>:</strong></div></td>
          <td><input name="password" type="text" size="50" maxlength="8"  /><span class="error">* <?php echo $passwordErr;?></span></td>
     
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td><div align="right"><strong>Emel</strong></div></td>
          <td><div align="center"><strong>:</strong></div></td>
          <td><input name="email" type="text" size="50"  /><span class="error">* <?php echo $emailErr;?></span></td>
        
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>&nbsp;</td>
          <td>&nbsp;</td>
          <td><input type="submit" value="Submit"/></td>
          
        </tr>
      </table>
    </form>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

it exactly no error, but when i load the page(the submit button is not even click) the password error has been displayed. other field error work just fine.

Comment: I checked your code. the error is in test_input() function as Fred pointed out. Other parts of your code works fine. Give the error message and we can understand the problem better.

Comment: @Rash sorry for that, posted the full code already :)

Comment: What error has been displayed?  Please show the exact error text.

Comment: simple, put your code into an IDE and you'll what's happening.

Comment: no error, but when i first load the page the password error has already displayed

Comment: fixed, the password is totally wrong dunno lah y

Comment: after the fix; try to enter anything other than a number for your id. You will see that the answer given below, has not given you a full solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your password block is outside of the POST block and that is why the `$passwordErr` is always set even before the form is submitted.

```
if (empty($_POST["password"])) {
     $passwordErr = "Password is required";
   } else {
     $password = test_input($_POST["password"]);
     // check if name only contains letters and whitespace
     if (!preg_match("/^[a-zA-Z0-9]+$/",$password)) {
       $passwordErr = "Special characters are not allowed"; 
     }
   }
```

Put it inside the block `if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST") {`

Also in your code `$nameErr = "Special characters are not allowed";`  is wrong. You must assign the error to $passwordErr like I have done in the code above.

Comment: and what about this stray variable `$website`? `test_input($_POST["id"])` will fail. This answer isn't a full solution.